# oct2py isn't seeing OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE environment variable (Windows)

Tags: python, octave, oct2py

So, I'm trying to use oct2py on Windows, like so:

```
from oct2py import octave
```

That's literally the only code I need to reproduce the error.

When I execute this, I get `OSError: Octave Executable not found, please add to path or set"OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE" environment variable`. However, I *have* already set `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE` as a system variable, which points to `"C:\Octave\Octave-4.4.1\bin\octave-cli-4.4.1.exe"`. Opening up the command line and running `%OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE%`  gives me the Octave CLI, so I know it's right.

I've tried rebooting. I've also tried adding the Octave folder to my Path and removing `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE`. Neither work.

EDIT: I've also tried using just `octave-cli.exe`, and I've tried doing `print(os.environ['OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE'])`, which returns the expected path.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 2):

In spite of what you mention in your comment:

> It appears that, somewhere along the line, octave.exe got replaced with octave-cli.exe. There is no longer an octave.exe distributed with the Octave package. Others have successfully pointed OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE at octave-cli.exe

Recently more people had a similar issue and the `oct2py` developers fixed it in the `5.0.0` version some hours ago. Actually they [said](https://github.com/blink1073/oct2py/issues/147#issuecomment-489132477):

> Ah, I see what the issue is here. The convenience `octave` instance is created before you get a chance to set the `executable` property. Given that fact, I think the only right answer is to remove the executable argument in favor of using `PATH` or the `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE` environment variable.

Anyway I had to adapt my code to make it work updating the environment variable `OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE`:

```
import shutil
import os
import sys

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    # os.environ['OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE'] = shutil.which('octave')
    # >> I had to replace this with this other line >>

    os.environ['OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE'] = shutil.which('octave-cli.exe')
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two executables, octave-cli.exe and octave-cli-4.4.1.exe.
What if you try the one without the version number?
I only needed to restart the Spyder IDE for it to work

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion... I've actually tried both, with no luck.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom what about just octave.exe instead of octave-cli?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (http://blink1073.github.io/oct2py/source/installation.html) mentions oct2py may in fact be tryin to find a file called octave.exe, not octave-cli.exe

Try modifying your OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE to point to that instead. Though, in theory, if octave.exe and octave-cli.exe both sit in the same directory, adding to path should have worked ... but try anyway!

Comment: It appears that, somewhere along the line, octave.exe got replaced with octave-cli.exe. There is no longer an octave.exe distributed with the Octave package. Others have successfully pointed OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE at octave-cli.exe. Thanks, though.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom might still be worth a try creating a symbolic link (or renaming) from octave-cli.exe to octave.exe though. (PS. Great honour, your eminence. Big fan of the liturgy :p )

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help so long after the OP, but here is what worked for me:

1. Download Octave as a .7z file and unzip it to hard disk
2. Run post-install.bat (from the folder entitled octave-5.2.0-w64 or something similar)
3. Restart Windows 10 machine (due to messages encountered during run of post-install.bat)
4. Run octave-firsttime.vbs
5. Quit the Octave program
6. Execute the following python code (in 3.7.6)

```
import os

pathToExecutable = (
    'D:\\wherever\\you\\put\\this\\octave-cli.exe'
)
os.environ['OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE'] = pathToExecutable
from oct2py import octave
```

I was running into a problem because, first of all, I failed to comprehend that I needed to install an Octave interpreter (I thought `oct2py` came with one) and then since I am not an administrator I figured I would never be able to install it, but I worked it out!

Comment: So I am just getting into using Octave, for the first time ever...step 5 above might not be necessary.  All I know is that it definitely does not cause an error with the import statement; I figured it might cause problems if both Python and GNU Octave were both calling the interpreter at the same time, but then again, maybe it wouldn't!

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 10 and local user installation of Octave 6.2.0 creating new user environment Variable:

OCTAVE_EXECUTABLE

and setting to:
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\GNU Octave\Octave-6.2.0\mingw64\bin\octave-cli.exe

worked for me. I did not need admin rights for this.