# Installed the oct2py package but is not recognized when imported

Tags: python-3.x, pip, oct2py

I have just installed the oct2py python package using the following command on my Windows:

```
pip install oct2py
```

However, whenever I try to import the package oct2py in my python script, I get the error:
`No module named "oct2py"`

What is it that is making me have this error?

Comment: Could it be because different python version and that your command pip install oct2py installed it to the python you have added to your environment variables? LMK.

Comment: Have not thought about this, but let me check please!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651597/oct2py-isnt-seeing-octave-executable-environment-variable-windows) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your environment variable from 'C:\Program Files\Python39' to this one 'C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39'.

Comment: Glad I helped :D