# Error when trying to install oct2py package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, octave, oct2py

I am trying to install to oct2py package to import in my python script. However whenever I run the command `pip install oct2py`  I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python37\python.exe"  "C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" ': file cannot be found.
```

How can I install oct2py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found the answer**

Deinstalled python and reinstalled it. I checked the environment variable and changed it from this one : 'C:\Program Files\Python39' to this one 'C:\Users\lsee\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39'.

Answer (score 0):

Is unable to locate your pip installer, easy fix is unusually to either upgrade or test pip :

```
# to upgrade your pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip 

pip --version 
# test you have pip in your machine
```

If your pip version is showing that means you have it installed, it could be a problem activating your virtual environnement, or your path.

It says the file cannot be locate, are you sure your path for Python and pip is correct ?

Comment: GR I tried your command `python -m pip install` and got this error `Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")`

Comment: I also checked the environment path, it seems correct to me...

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, try ``pip install --upgrade pip `` which OS are you using ?

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Try the answer from @frederic, please try upgrading or installing a package, does it fail only with ``oct2py``? Can you output your pip version ?

Comment: GR, problem solved and oct2py installed. However whenever I try to import it in my python script I get the error asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773291/installed-the-oct2py-package-but-is-not-recognized-when-imported?noredirect=1#comment116291409_65773291)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
python -m pip install oct2py
```

This should work (as `python -m pip install` gave not errors)